# Changing bags into arrays in Pig Latin

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm doing some transformations on some data set and need to publish to a sane looking format. Current my final set looks like this when I run describe:

```
{memberId: long,companyIds: {(subsidiary: long)}}
```

I need it to look like this:

```
{memberId: long,companyIds: [long] }
```

where `companyIds` is the key to an array of ids of type long?

I'm really struggling with how to manipulate things in this way? Any ideas? I've tried using `FLATTEN` and other commands to know avail. I'm using AvroStorage to write the files into this schema:

The field schema I need to write this data to looks like this:

```
"fields": [
        { "name": "memberId", "type": "long"},
        { "name": "companyIds", "type": {"type": "array", "items": "int"}}
      ]
```

Comment: There is no array type in Pig - I suggest that you write your own store function to transform the current schema into a more friendly text format - see http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/udf.html#load-store-functions

Comment: Hmm, I would but I'm trying to leverage the AvroStorage() functions. I've edited the question to include my output schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a bit old, but I recently ran into the same problem.

Based on the [avrostorage documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/PIG/AvroStorage), using the latest version of pig and avrostorage, it is possible to directly cast bag to avro array.

In your case, you may want something like:

```
STORE blah INTO 'blah' USING AvroStorage('schema','{your schema}');
```

where the array field in the schema is

```
{  
    "name":"companyIds",
    "type":[  
        "null",
        {  
            "type":"array",
            "items":"long"
        }
    ],
    "doc":"company ids"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no array type in PIG (http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#data-types). However, if all you need is a good looking output and if you don't have too many elements in companyIds, you may want to write a simple UDF that converts the bag into a nice formatted string.

Java code

```
public class BagToString extends EvalFunc<String>
{
    @Override
    public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException
    {
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
        DataBag bag = (DataBag) input.get(0);
        if (bag.size() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        for (Iterator<Tuple> it = bag.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Tuple t = it.next();
            strings.add(t.get(0).toString());
        }
        return StringUtils.join(strings, ":");
    }
}
```

PIG script

```
 foo = foreach bar generate memberId, BagToString(companyIds);
```